# Create thumnail to existing image with GD

Tags: php

I want to create thumb for existing image. I have three image input fields and only want for 1st image to make thumb.

```
$_FILES['img_1']['name']
$_FILES['img_2']['name']
$_FILES['img_3']['name']
```

And for create i usee this function

```
function createThumbnail($filename, $path_to_image_directory, $final_width_of_image, $path_to_thumbs_directory) {

    if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromgif($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
    }else if (preg_match('/[.](jpeg)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
    }

    $ox = imagesx($im);
    $oy = imagesy($im);

    $nx = $final_width_of_image;
    $ny = floor($oy * ($final_width_of_image / $ox));

    $nm = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);

    imagecopyresized($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,$nx,$ny,$ox,$oy);

    if(!file_exists($path_to_thumbs_directory)) {
        if(!mkdir($path_to_thumbs_directory)) {
            die("There was a problem. Please try again!");
        }
    }

    imagejpeg($nm, $path_to_thumbs_directory . $filename);
    $tn = '<img src="' . $path_to_thumbs_directory . $filename . '" alt="image" />';
    $tn .= '<br />Congratulations. Your file has been successfully uploaded, and a      thumbnail has been created.';
    echo $tn;
}
```

And when i call `createThumbnail($_FILES["img_1"]["tmp_name"],'./uploads', 370, './uploads');`

Files are successfull moved to directory `img_1, img_2, img_3` but thumb is not created. I set error to E_ALL to see and i get to many warrnings.

> Notice: Undefined variable: im in
>   /var/www/http_myoffice/petbook/web/ogi/admin/dodaj_vozilo_proccess.php
>   on line 21
>
> Warning: imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in
>   /var/www/http_myoffice/petbook/web/ogi/admin/dodaj_vozilo_proccess.php
>   on line 21
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: im in
>   /var/www/http_myoffice/petbook/web/ogi/admin/dodaj_vozilo_proccess.php
>   on line 22
>
> Warning: imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in
>   /var/www
>
> Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/
>
> Warning: imagecreatetruecolor(): Invalid image dimensions in /var/www
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: im in /var/www/
>
> Warning: imagecopyresized() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in /var/www/
>
> Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>   in /var/www/ image Congratulations. Your file has been successfully
>   uploaded, and a thumbnail has been created.

Comment: What filename are you passing to the above function whenever it fails and returns the above error?

Comment: $_FILES["img_1"]["name"]

Comment: Did you even try to `var_dump($im)`? It's definitely `NULL` and all your `preg_match`s don't work

Comment: @Zend What I meant is when you received this error, what was the value of $_FILES["img_1"]["name"]

Comment: And if you do `echo($_FILES["img_1"]["tmp_name"])` you'll definitely see that there's no extension with this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you pass the temp name of the image to the function. This temp name has no file extension. You have to pass the name (with extension) and the temp name (path to file on disk).

If you want to get rid of the regex search for the file type, a user could upload a file with wrong extension, you can use `$image = imagecreatefromstring( file_get_contents( $path ) );`. PHP GD will get the file type on its own.

Changed PHP Code:

```
function createThumbnail($tempname, $filename, $final_width_of_image, $path_to_thumbs_directory) {

    $im = imagecreatefromstring( file_get_contents( $tempname ) );

    $ox = imagesx($im);
    $oy = imagesy($im);

    $nx = $final_width_of_image;
    $ny = floor($oy * ($final_width_of_image / $ox));

    $nm = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);

    imagecopyresized($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,$nx,$ny,$ox,$oy);

    if(!file_exists($path_to_thumbs_directory)) {
        if(!mkdir($path_to_thumbs_directory)) {
            die("There was a problem. Please try again!");
        }
    }

    imagejpeg($nm, $path_to_thumbs_directory . $filename . '.jpg');
    $tn = '<img src="' . $path_to_thumbs_directory . $filename . '" alt="image" />';
    $tn .= '<br />Congratulations. Your file has been successfully uploaded, and a      thumbnail has been created.';
    echo $tn;
}
```

Edit:
You can call this function:

```
createThumbnail($_FILES["img_1"]["tmp_name"],$_FILES["img_1"]["name"], 370, './uploads');
```